# configure grunt to prevent minifying inline scripts

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

How can I configure grunt and/or the usemin step so that it doesnt touch an inline script inside the body?

Suppose the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script id="an-example" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <b>{{:data}}</b>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run `grunt serve` to run it locally, all is ok, but when i package it with `grunt`, I can't find the script inside the index.html.

This is part of my Gruntfile.js:

```
usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= config.dist %>',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the script section was wrapped inside the following comments:

```
<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

that instructed Grunt to compress/minify/uglify the code inside the same main.js file.

Moving the  sections outside any build comment solved the issue.